# From what age onward can we see that a child is homosexual?

Tags: development, lgbtq, sexual-development

Is there a lower limit to the age at which one could first determine that a child is homosexual?

If so, what age is it?

Comment: When they start showing sexual behavior? (So the definition of 'sexual' is back in your court now. Varies by culture.)

Comment: You can never tell, and it's pointless trying to second guess. Read this: Former US Senator discovered his sexual preferences changed at the age of 70. http://www.nytimes.com/2016/04/24/opinion/sunday/findinglove-again-this-time-with-a-man.html?_r=0.

Comment: Famous quote: "**Argue for your limitations and they are yours.**" - Richard Bach

Comment: Is it a boy or a girl? Isn't it a bit early to impose a role on a child at the moment of birth...it will what it wants to be.

Comment: the question is not unclear IMO

Comment: Highly recommend reselecting an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: TL;DR -->I do not believe there is an age cap. From the moment the child is born, they learn from their surroundings and parents how to act/react to all situations. Some parts of a child are nurture (how they handle anger, gender roles, etc...), some are nature (liking sports vs art, etc...), but children are just experiencing life, they do not categorize themselves like we do.

I inferred some things about the OP's question because as it stands explicitly, the answer is a very short, "No". However, I felt that was unhelpful answer so I inferred that the OP must have had more going on behind the scenes that wasn't expressed in the post.

---

Children learn about life by watching others and by guidance from their parents. My 5 yr old boy likes to paint his nails because he has watched my wife do it. By no means does that mean he is homosexual. He simply saw someone else doing it, and tried doing it himself.

What ever the child you are thinking about is doing, he/she is probably just getting influence from other sources like TV or school. It is up to you to guide your child as you wish. If you want them to be homosexual, by all means tell them their behavior means they are homosexual. If you do not want your child to be homosexual, realize they are just experimenting. Possibly tell them that is something the other gender usually does, but do not prohibit them from doing it because the child really is just finding out about life.

Another example is when my 5yr old was putting my wife's hair ties and such in his hair, or putting on her bra. I just told him he was "being silly, putting on mama's clothes" and such. And he really was, he just likes being silly. He grew out of that and now likes to be silly by dancing all crazy like.

EDIT:
nocomprende wrote a comment that I feel should not be missed, so I got his permission to put it in this answer.

"...we [adults] have a definition of homosexuality, but children simply have preferences and behavior. We think that a definition makes something so, but there is no homosexuality until there is intent. That is in the mind, not visible. It makes no difference until intent is acted on."

As NoComprende says, we should see that our children ***ARE*** innocence. They ***ARE*** kindness and love. That is what they are made of at a young age.

As a personal rant, unfortunately in our society, "growing up" could be defined as the process of losing that innocence, love, and kindness.

Comment: Not sure exactly why you were downvoted. I suppose that your "*If you want...*" statements are rhetorical and not actually meant to indicate that you can make up someone else's mind for them. But it reads a little funny. Perhaps edit for simplicity and clarity? This could take some effort to write convincingly, since it is a dicey topic.

Comment: @nocomprende because it doesn't answer the question. All it says is 'kids learn some behaviours from their parents'.

Comment: @dwjohnston I think rather that this answer is saying that we have a *definition* of homosexuality, but children simply have preferences and behavior. We think that a definition makes something so, but there is no homosexuality until there is intent. That is in the mind, not visible. It makes no difference until intent is acted on. We all have ideas of doing things that we never do, for various reasons. Does that make us... anything? I think that the question is wrongly put. Like saying how do we know it will rain? When it rains. Not until. Does that make it a "rainy day"?

Comment: @dwjohnston I inferred some things about the OP's question because as it stands explicitly, the answer is a very short, "No". However, I felt that was unhelpful answer so I inferred that the OP must have had more going on behind the scenes that wasn't expressed in the post. I feel if you would take off your biased goggles and just read the answer, you may find it helpful.

Comment: This answers more than just the question being asked, well done.

Comment: @nocomprende Can I edit my answer to include some of what you wrote in your comment? You read between the lines quite well and I really like how you wrote it.

Comment: Sure, borrow away. Thank you for the compliment.

Comment: No vote from me either way, but I feel like this answer conflates sexual orientation and gender roles.  They're two very different things.

Comment: I disagree that this answer is well-written. Even after reading it twice, and with the addition of no comprendre, I'm still not sure I get your point.

Comment: @Erik NoComprende's edit was not supposed to clarify anything, I just felt it was an important point I didn't want ppl to miss if it was buried in a comment.

Comment: Then I certainly don't understand your point.

Comment: @Erik I do admit that the answer has evolved quite a bit from the original answer, and it does seem to be side-tracked a bit. However, can you expound at all?

Comment: Not really, because I'm not sure what you're trying to say. You don't really seem to be addressing the original question, from what I can see.

Comment: @Erik Ok. I made some edits that removed superfluous text, as well as a short answer at the top. If you want some more context, read my comment  that is in reply to dwjohnston

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39405/discussion-between-jeff-clark-and-erik).

Comment: I really don't understand why this answer encourages pressuring the child to be a certain sexuality.

Comment: It does not. You may have missed the point.

Answer (score 17):

A person may discover their preferences, or find new preferences, to almost anything at any point in their life.

Comment: And these may change any number of times throughout their life.

Comment: @RoryAlsop You mean, sexuality is... not somehow *different* than everything else about being human?!? Outrageous! : )

Comment: This sounds lovely but seems less like an attempt to answer the question at hand than an attempt to make a socio-political statement (i.e., it should be a comment). OP is not asking how to discover their *own* preferences.

Answer (score 16):

At the age that the child tells you. You don't "discover" another person's sexuality, that is something each person finds for themselves.

Comment: I like this and I expect that it has some truth to it but given that [this is an area of ongoing research](https://gendercenter.genetics.ucla.edu/about), the skeptic in me demands some evidence out of this answer.

Comment: I'd say at the age the child tells you, and understands what he or she is saying.

Answer (score 12):

I have some experience with this as a parent! So speaking from experience: there is no set age at which you can tell what a child's sexual preferences, gender identity, gender expression, political tastes, favourite baseball team, or preference for cats versus dogs are/will be, but there is one critical thing you can do to make that age *earlier* than it otherwise would have been. Some of those things in the list are facetious, some of them are likely nature, some are nurture, and others are choices, but all of them are affected the same way by doing this one thing:

**Make sure your child feels confident and safe telling you about their life, thoughts, and feelings.**

Feeling safe and confident comes from knowing that they are loved and that they don't risk personal rejection for revealing something. How you react any time they reveal something they feel sensitive about is a test for the next time they have something on their minds; each time you react positively and without judgement gives them more confidence that you won't reject them, and makes it more likely you will be shared with in the future.

So though there is no age limit, you can help ensure your child will reveal personal things earlier rather than later (perhaps much later), by ensuring they feel that they will always be accepted by and acceptable to you when they do.

Comment: Though this doesn't exactly answer the question, it's still a lovely answer, and applicable to so many things. +1

Comment: @anongoodnurse It does say there is no specific age, which is I think as much an answer as it's possible to write that's directly addressed to the question's assumptions. I guess that's a shortcoming of the answer that I'm willing to accept. :)

Comment: I like this, as it is something that needs to be done for a child in any/every way possible. A child knowing it is loved and that he/she can come to you for anything is imperative for the child's healthy development.